# How to migrate data to a new cluster / datacenter?

Tags: cassandra

I have an old cassandra cluster 2.x and now a new one 3.x.

What is the best way to copy all data over to the new one which has a different topology? Could I "add" the new 3.x cluster to the old one, replicate and then detach?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a backup from the old cluster and export them to the new cluster. If you really want to add the nodes to make your cluster bigger, then add the old nodes later to the new cluster one by one.

You can follow my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39804098/4610541) for migration issue.
You can look over [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html), for how `COPY` works. And also you can look over [here](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/simple-data-importing-and-exporting-with-cassandra) for datastax's import/export blog.