# Should I Upgrade Cassandra 2.0.17 to 3.0.x? Or Reinstall?

Tags: cassandra

I am new in cassandra and i have cassandra version 2.0.17 on centos 7. Search the web to to upgrade to version 3.0.x but not get the exact idea and still confusing. Should i uninstall the old version and install new version?.Please, If it is possible, i need more detail help. Thank everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to uninstall the older version. Check out his link
[Cassandra upgrade from 2.0.x to 2.1.x or 3.0.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796304/cassandra-upgrade-from-2-0-x-to-2-1-x-or-3-0-x)

For installing Cassandra check out (Ubuntu)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-cassandra-and-run-a-single-node-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to 2.1.9 first(uninstall older version of Cassandra and install 2.1.9) then you can upgrade directly to 3.x but don't forget to upgrade sstables.